# "fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory" when installing rpf package in rstudio

Tags: r, package, rstudio, eigen

I need the rpf package as a dependency of the MBESS package. During the installation process rstudio does the following:

```
    Installing package into ‘/home/gata/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rpf_0.59.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 347458 bytes (339 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 339 KB

    * installing *source* package ‘rpf’ ...
    ** Paket ‘rpf’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
    ** libs
    g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/gata/R/x86_64-pc-linux-        gnu-library/3.4/RcppEigen/include"   -fopenmp    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ba81quad.cpp -o ba81quad.o
    In file included from ba81quad.cpp:18:0:
    rpf.h:25:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    #include "Eigen/Core"
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: recipe for target 'ba81quad.o' failed
    make: *** [ba81quad.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rpf’
    * removing ‘/home/gata/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rpf’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘rpf’ had non-zero exit status

    The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpPz090Z/downloaded_packages’
```

I researched the Eigen library, but I have no idea how I could fix this in the installation process.

Is there a suggestion how to solve this issue?

Information about my OS and R version:

- R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
- Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
- Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which command did you use? `install.packages("MBESS")`? `install.packages("rpf")`? Something else (e.g. `devtools::install_cran()`)? Were there any options you passed to any of these (e.g. `dependencies = "Depends"`)?

Comment: Hey duckmayr. Thank you very much for commenting! I solved it by installing RcppEigen packages. 
Anyway, maybe if somebody else will have the question again: I tried installing in RStudio GUI, RTerminal (install.packages() for each of the dependencies) and in the terminal via sudo install <tar.gz file>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved it by simply installing RcppEigen package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppEigen/index.html). 
Still no clue why this wasn't supposed as a dependency.

Comment: Good practical solution (+1). I'm also unsure why the dependency wasn't installed for you (thus my comment to the question -- thanks for response also). `MBESS` depends on `OpenMx`, which in turn Links To `rpf`, which in turn Links To `RcppEigen`, so the default value for `dependencies` for `install.packages()` (`NA`, which is interpreted as `c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo")` should have brought in `RcppEigen` -- it did on my machine running Ubuntu 18.04.1 and R 3.5.1.